# I want to generate QR Code encrypted in such a way that it is only read by own QRScanner app

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

I am making a social app. I want to generate QRCode for each user profile that he can share with others. QR Code has user image in centre with his total number of posts. Using some libraries I am able to generate the QR. 
But that code can be read by any QR Scanner. I don't want this to happen.

I only want my QR Scanner to scan these userprofile QR's

Comment: What is your perceived benefit of not allowing other applications read your QR codes?

Comment: Maybe you just want to encrypt or otherwise obscrure the text being encoded?

Comment: Just encrypt the text using which you are creating the QR code and decrypt after reading with your app.

Comment: Please see the snapchat, fb messenger QR functionality, they do not allow other QR scanner to read their QR. @BenBoxler

Answer (score 2):

A QR code simply contains whatever text / string put in it.  You're free to encrypt the content string prior to generating the code (and decrypt it after reading the code).   Other applications will not be able to decrypt the code.  You may want to do the encryption/decryption on your server instead of relying on code/keys on the device, for security purposes.